# error while setting proxy on selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

i using selenium and chrome driver with javascript (node js)
and i want to reduce / disable the bot detection
so i understand that change proxy can help with this situation.
i config the proxy setting but i get error of proxy err connection
it only appear when i add this config
the code i show is only the config of the proxy and the driver
without the setting of the proxy its working but the bots gets me

```
const { Builder, Options, Browser, By, Key, until, logging, WebDriver } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
require("chromedriver");
  const proxy = "5.161.125.25:8080";
  let option = new chrome.Options().addArguments(`--proxy-server=https://${proxy}`);
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.CHROME).setChromeOptions(option).build();
```